# CSS is not responding in Edge as it is in Chrome for Date Input Placeholders and 'content'

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, microsoft-edge

I have 2 separate questions, but both relate to how Chrome displays stuff vs Edge. Basically, I am looking to make the 2 items look the same in Edge as they do in Chrome

**1. Date input's placeholders**

Chrome - As it should be, the placeholder is very light.
[image: Chrome Date Input]

Edge = the placeholder is still dark. I can't figure out how to make it respond to the CSS
[image: Edge Date Input]

I tried using input[type="date"] and then following it with both the ::webkit- and also the ::-ms. Neither of those worked. I tried date with and without quotes around it. I tried adding ::webkit-datetime-edit-text as a few things suggested. I cleared my cache and the other CSS elements changed, so I know it's not that. I've added and removed important tags. Nothing has even almost worked.

```
/*This is for Google Chrome*/
input::placeholder, input[type=date]::-webkit-datetime-edit {
    color: rgba(29, 55, 92, .3) !important;
    font-size: 1em !important;
    font-style: oblique;
}

/*This is for MS Edge*/
input[type="text"]::-ms-input-placeholder, input[type="tel"]::-ms-input-placeholder, input[type="email"]::-ms-input-placeholder, input[type="number"]::-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: rgba(29, 55, 92, .3) !important;
    font-size: 1em !important;
    font-style: oblique;
}

input[type=date]:focus::-webkit-datetime-edit {
    color: black !important;
}


input[type=date]:valid::-webkit-datetime-edit {
    color: black !important;
}
```

**2. 'Content' color not working**

**EDIT:** Here is a codepen for the placeholders: [Custom Checkboxes](https://codepen.io/humanhickory/pen/YzzKGLM)

The color and positioning are not working in Edge. However, Edge does know that they exist:

[image: Example that Edge Knows about the CSS]

I see that display is crossed out. Does that have something to do with it? It doesn't do this in Chrome, so I don't know how I would fix that.

Chrome - The checkbox is white and properly fitted inside the box
[image: Chrome Checkbox]

Edge - The checkbox is green and isn't in the right spot
[image: Edge Checkbox]

```
.checkmark, .checkmarkSquare {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #eee; /*light grayish-beige*/
    border-radius: 50%;
}
/* Create the checkmark */
.checkmark:after, .checkmarkSquare:after {
    content: '\02714'; 
    color: white;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Different browsers display things differently.

Comment: Yes. Obviously. Which is why I'm looking for a work around that will allow me to display them the same. Users should have the same look and feel regardless of browser. There are some elements that are exclusive to a browser (like alerts and required fields) but the css should produce the same results in all browsers.

Answer (score -1):

> 1. Date input's placeholders

About this issue, I have tried to test it with MS Edge and I was able to produce the issue. It can be possible that it is Edge default behavior.I will try to submit the feedback regarding this issue.

As a workaround, I suggest you could try to use the text type input to enter the date. we could change the text type input placeholder color.

Sample code as below:

```
<style>
    ::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
        color: red; /*rgba(29, 55, 92, .3)  gainsboro red*/
        opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
    }

    :-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
        color: red; /*rgba(29, 55, 92, .3)*/
    }

    ::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
        color: red; /*rgba(29, 55, 92, .3)*/
    }
</style>
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
```

The screenshot as below:
[image]

Besides, since the latest version of Microsoft Edge browser is Chromium based, if we using them, your code works well, we could change the date type input placeholder color. You can download it from [here](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/).

> 'Content' color not working

whether you are using some CSS theme? I try to add some checkbox and can't reproduce the problem like your screenshot show. The result like this:

[image]

It seems that this is the browser default behavior, you could try to use the Microsoft Edge (chromium based) to display the web page.

**Edit**:

> 'Content' color not working
>
> EDIT: Here is a codepen for the placeholders: [Custom Checkboxes](https://codepen.io/humanhickory/pen/YzzKGLM)

Please refer to the following code:

```
<style>
    .center {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50vh;
        left: 40vw;
    }
    /* The container */
    .container {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 35px;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 22px;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }

        /* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
        .container input {
            position: absolute;
            opacity: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
        }

    /* Create a custom checkbox */
    .checkmark {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
        background-color: #eee;
    }

    /* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
    .container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

    /* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
    .container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
        background-color: #1D375C;
        box-shadow: darkgray 2px 2px 8px;
    }

    /* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
    .checkmark:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
    }

    /* Show the checkmark when checked */
    .container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
        display: block;
    }

    /* Style the checkmark/indicator */
    .container .checkmark:after {
        left: 9px;
        top: 5px;
        width: 5px;
        height: 10px;
        border: solid white;
        border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
</style>
<div class="center">
    <div>
        <label class="container">
            One
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="container">
            Two
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="container">
            Three
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="container">
            Four
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: I'll try a variation of your solution for the top placeholder one. I still want it to behave like a date input, but we'll see. perhaps something like this:  <input type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onfocusout="(this.type='text')" name="DateOfIncident" class="form-control col-12" required/>

Comment: As far as using Microsoft Edge Chronium, this is going to be launched for 'public' use, so it needs to cater to various needs. So although using that version would solve my problem when I'm using it, it wouldn't solve the problem. Also, my checkboxes are custom where the default one is hidden. I'm just not sure why 'content' wont allow me to style it.

Comment: About the checkboxes and content issue, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).